# React bootstrap table not changing sizePerPageList

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am trying to modify my react-bootstrap-table2, however it is not complying to one of the options that I pass in. Here is what part of my return statement looks like for options that gets passed into the table component. Here is a helpful [link](https://react-bootstrap-table.github.io/react-bootstrap-table2/docs/pagination-props.html) so far

```
return {
    options: {
      bootstrap4: true,
      bordered: false,
      displayCaret: true,
      striped: true,
      showFilters: true,
      keyName: "key",
      keyField: "key",
      showColumnBorders: false,
      showPagination: true,
      sizePerPageList: [ 5, 10, 20 ],
      defaultSorted: [
        {
          dataField: "name",
          order: "asc"
        }
      ]
    },
```

I am setting sizePerPageList clearly but it does not change it in the UI. It just shows a dropdown of 10, 25, 30, and 50 instead 5, 10, and 20. Am I doing this the wrong way?

Here is how I implemented it:

```
<SchemaTable
          options={SchemaSettings.options}
          schema={mySchema}
          data={mappedData}
          className="disable-hot-table-cells"
        />
```

SchemaSettings.options is that options list getting retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was that I needed to siphon it off into its own object:

```
options: {
      bootstrap4: true,
      bordered: false,
      displayCaret: true,
      striped: true,
      showFilters: true,
      keyName: "key",
      keyField: "key",
      showColumnBorders: false,
      showPagination: true,
      defaultSorted: [
        {
          dataField: "name",
          order: "asc"
        }
      ],
      paginationOptions: {
        sizePerPage: 20,
        page: 1,
        alwaysShowAllBtns: true,
        hideSizePerPage: false,
        sizePerPageList: [5,10,20]
      }
```